# Grouping Data in TableView from Core Data in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am having trouble finding out how to group my sections by a property in my Core Data database. This is what my DB looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKwLx.png).  I am trying to group my tableView by the dueDate property.  I have loaded up my Attributes in an array and that is how they are displayed.  I plan on customizing the headers as well, so I would like to use the standard tableView methods.  Here is the code from my ViewController.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var taskArray = [Task]()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view functions
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Date"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 65.00
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = taskArray[indexPath.row].name ?? "Add Items"

        if taskArray[indexPath.row].dueTime == nil {
            cell.timeLabel.text = ""
        } else {
            let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            cell.timeLabel.text = timeFormatter.string(from: taskArray[indexPath.row].dueTime!)
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: Add New Task
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "newTaskSegue", sender: self)
    }


    // MARK: Save & Load Data
    func saveData() {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueDate", ascending: false)
        let sort2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueTime", ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort, sort2]

        do {
            taskArray = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error loading data \(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What Type and format is dueDate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily group your data using `NSFetchedResultsController`. One parameter in the instantiation of `NSFetchedResultsController` specifically allows you to group your results into sections by passing the `keyPath` of an attribute that constitutes the predicate for section grouping.

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW26) explains this pretty clearly, with example code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let frc = <#Fetched results controller#> {
        return frc.sections!.count
    }
    return 0
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sections = self.<#Fetched results controller#>?.sections else {
        fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
    }
    let sectionInfo = sections[section]
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = <#Get the cell#>
    guard let object = self.<#Fetched results controller#>?.object(at: indexPath) else {
        fatalError("Attempt to configure cell without a managed object")
    }
    // Configure the cell with data from the managed object.
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    guard let sectionInfo = <#Fetched results controller#>?.sections?[section] else {
        return nil
    }
    return sectionInfo.name
}
override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return <#Fetched results controller#>?.sectionIndexTitles
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    guard let result = <#Fetched results controller#>?.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index) else {
        fatalError("Unable to locate section for \(title) at index: \(index)")
    }
    return result
}
```

It is generally a Good Idea(tm) to use an NSFetchedResultsController when dealing with CoreData and `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` as you get handy notifications (through a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`) when your data changes that allow you to insert or remove cells from your displayed view.